# How do I mount a qcow2 disk image?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I have a QEMU virtual machine that uses a qcow2 disk image.

How can I mount its filesystem without powering on the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qemu-nbd` program, It is part of the `qemu-kvm` package. Look [here](http://alexeytorkhov.blogspot.com/2009/09/mounting-raw-and-qcow2-vm-disk-images.html)